# WPF Wait for User Input

Tags: wpf

I'm adding user authorization into my WPF application and I'm having a problem with the login screen.

I have the login screen showing but the application continues to process the current action.

IE. 
Show the main window
1. check if user is allowed to view the main window
2. User is not allowed
3. Show login screen
4. Load the main window

I would like the application to pause at the login screen until the user is authenticated with the correct authorization.

Comment: You can't pause Application or UI Thread. Just start processes after successful authorization.

Comment: What method do you use to show the login screen?

Comment: I've used AOP to intercept the getter of properties with the custom attribute of Authorise etc

Answer (score 1):

You can show the login window with `Window.ShowDialog`, ShowDialog will return only after the window closes.

If you want to display the login screen inside the same window it get's a little bit messier, you call `Dispatcher.PushFrame` where you want to stop and set `DispatcherFrame.Continue = false;` (on the frame objects you passed to PushFrame, obviously) to resume execution.